# What is the correct wine for kiddush in accordance with all the poskim.?

Tags: halacha, grapes-wine, kiddush

I have heard of mevushal not being used for kiddush. Now most wine labels indicate whether the wine is mevushal. But are there other things to be concerned about?

The following are halakhic concerns I've learned.

1. The wine should not contain sugar or alchohol not provided by the grapes.
2. It should not have extra coloring.
3. It should not have been 'treated' to stop it fermenting.
4. Although one can squeeze grapes and use them for kiddush, they should ferment for at least one day.
5. It should be the best wine a person can afford. Like any mitsva, one should use the best.

**Are there other concerns to keep in mind?**

**Have I made any mistakes?**

Comment: @annex I follow rambam's shitah and most manufactured wines are unfit for qiddush for resasons you have stated. Therefore my friend squeezes his own wine and let's it sit for 3 days which is considered to be the beginning if fermentation so it is "wine" or I know a person who doesn't follow rambam but is also trying to follow the holocho properly, therefore he makes his own wine no sugar or additives, pure grapes, which he lets sit and ferment and makes wine that way. I am not sure if he sells then to everyone, but it makes more sense to make your own wine.

Comment: @annex It's nice that you have an answer to your own question.  On this website, to answer your own question, you should post it as an answer, not put it into the question.  If you are here to state and not to ask, that's okay, but you still need to do it in the Question/Answer format.  That's why I removed the bit about red wine.  It wasn't related to a question, but to an answer.  By the way, adding in the sources for these concerns would be very useful.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8670/what-makes-a-wine-valid-for-kiddush?rq=1

Comment: @Menachem, oh, heh, I guess this is a duplicate, no?

Comment: @msh210: could be

Comment: @msh this one is more like "how can I be super machmir with my wine choice in every way?"

Comment: It should not be white

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you thought it obvious, but you didn't mention that the wine should be red not white, as the Ramban held white wine is invalid (O.C. 272, 4).

Answer (score 0):

Last week I heard a posek on http://radio2000.co.il , who discussed the issue of diluting of wines and grape juices by manufacturers, the bracha on wine in such cases and differences between Ashkenazim and Sefardim.

Because it's hard for customers to know what happens in the production of a given wine, he said that a rule of thumb regarding this issue is that with any dry (not semi-dry) wine with a reliable hechsher, a person is on the safe side.

Comment: That's interesting, since I've "always" heard that we prefer sweet wines for kiddush because of the sweetness of {Shabbat, Yom Tov}.

Comment: That may be. But the problem is that the 'sweet' wines are not really wine at all only from grapes.