# In what case can a wine made from the "Fruit of the Vine" be kosher but not acceptable for kiddush?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, grapes-wine, kiddush

I saw a post the other day where a religious Jew posted a picture of a new wine he got and clarified that it was made from the "fruit of the vine" and yet it wasn't good for kiddush. What kind of wines can fall into this category?

Comment: dupe of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8670/what-makes-a-wine-valid-for-kiddush or http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29410/what-is-the-correct-wine-for-kiddush-in-accordance-with-all-the-poskim

Comment: When you say "Fruit of the Vine", do you mean that was the blessing? Are you asking how a beverage could have the blessing "Who creates the fruit of the vine" and yet still not qualify for Kiddush?

Comment: @Menachem I believed it referred to the bracha. Not a beverage though. This was *specifically* a wine.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not a common position, some say that as wine that was cooked couldn't be used as a Temple libation, it can't be used for kiddush either.

Wine that has molds growing on top is invalid for kiddush.

Wine diluted beyond a certain point.

I'm sure there are others, but those are the first that come to mind. (BTW there are scholars in the Conservative movement that will consider wine kosher if it is 100% vegetarian, but not good-enough-for-kiddush unless made by Jews. The Orthodox position is it's only kosher if made by Jews.)

Comment: By cooked wine do you mean mevushal wine? I'm not understanding the 100% vegetarian position though. Is this just a Conservative psak or is this based on some weird Rambamist psak?

Comment: I don't doubt you, but I'm wondering about your sources. *Who* holds this?

Comment: White wine. Mevushal wine. Wine with added sugar.

Comment: What wine isn't 100% vegetarian?  Are we just talking about equipment here, or ingredients?

Comment: @MonicaCellio, I have heard that some people use finings that may be treif, however I would think that due to the lack of effect on the flavour, that they should be batel b'rov.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - Some finings certainly are treif, and although they don't impart flavour, they do improve the product and are added deliberately for this purpose, so I am not sure that all would agree on them being batel b'rov.