# Opinions concerning using other beverages for kiddush and "cups of blessing"

Tags: halacha, grapes-wine, kiddush, havdalah

What are the major rabbinic opinions today concerning the suitability of substituting  another beverage for wine (or grape juice) for kiddush and other "cups of blessing," e.g., havdalah or Passover seder's four cups? Can one use another beverage even if wine is available? If one finds something distasteful, does that disqualify it from use?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8670/759

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2180/759

Comment: As mentioned in Shalom's answer, there's a difference between the nighttime *kiddush* and the daytime *kiddush* in this regard.

Comment: Pesach, the four cups need to be wine, not even grape juice, absent a really compelling reason. So I learned, and see here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70786/1516

Answer (score 2):

Friday night -- either wine, or challah.

Shabbos morning kiddush, as well as havdalah -- better with wine. Acceptable with any "beverage of the land." (How do you balance "better" vs. "acceptable"? AYLOR.) Beer definitely works as "beverage of the land." Hard liquor -- there's a discussion about how much you'd have to drink. Rabbi Ovadiah Yosef quotes some sephardic opinions that the beverage must be fermentable -- I assume apple juice would still count? Otherwise (at least for Ashkenazim) I've generally heard coffee, tea, milk, apple juice, orange juice. Many poskim allow soda (though the diet versions might be pushing it); Rav Moshe Feinstein didn't. "But they serve it at all the fancy weddings!", someone asked him. "Still no", he replied.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12069/minimum-shiur-for-kiddush-on-liquor#comment18118_5438

Comment: According to whom is this opinion?

Comment: I have seen discussions as to whether or not beer is still chaar medinah. Some hold that it no longer qualifies. Soda is called "flavored water" so it is like drinking water. Some say tea or coffee are also "flavored water"

Comment: I've seen someone use milk (havdala) but heard from a different source it wasn't allowed