# May one use bread for havdallah?

Tags: halacha, havdalah, bread

One may use bread for Kiddush if wine or grape juice are not available but may one use bread for havdallah when wine or grape juice are not available?

Comment: http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=1184

Answer (score 3):

One cannot use bread for *havdalah*. If one has no wine or grape juice, one can use [*chamar medinah*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38305/14850). ([Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayyim 296:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.296.2?lang=bi))

Comment: Unless Sunday is Yom Tov, then you can use bread

Comment: For other readers, what @DoubleAA implies is that when Yom Tov follows Shabbat, the Kiddush incorporates havdallah. As the "main" prayer is Kiddush, one may use bread for Kiddush.

Comment: This answer is definitive for Sephardim (as supported by @Yishai's comment above), does it hold for Ashkenazim as well?

Comment: Yes. The ruling of the Shulchan Aruch seems to be uncontested.